# How many times I can partition the array into 2 parts with equal sum?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to find a number of times that I can partition the array into 2 non-empty parts such that the sum of the elements in the left partition is equal to the sum of the elements in the right partition.

After each successful partition, we discards either the left partition or the right partition and continues playing by using the remaining partition as array.

Initially, there is an array, `a` , containing N integers. `N <= 2^14`

```
static int Compute(int[] a, int arraySize)
{
     return ComputeNumberOfPartition(a.ToList(), arraySize,  0);
}

static int ComputeNumberOfPartition(List<int> a, int N, int points)
{
     List<int> left = new List<int>();
     List<int> right = new List<int>();

     for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
     {
         if (sum(left) <= sum(right)) { left.Add(a[i]);  }
         else                         { right.Add(a[i]); }
     }

     if (sum(left) == sum(right))
     {
         return left.Count >= right.Count ? 
                ComputeNumberOfPartition(left, left.Count, ++points) :
                ComputeNumberOfPartition(right, right.Count, ++points);
     }

     return points;
}

static int sum(List<int> a)
{
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; ++i)
     {
         sum += a[i];
     }

     return sum;
}
```

For example:

`input1 3 3 3`

`output1 0`

We cannot partition  into 2 parts having equal sums. Therefore, her maximum possible score is 0.

`input2 4 1 0 1 1 0 1`

`output2 3`

My solution is very slow. How can we solve it more efficiently?
This problem from [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-splitting)

Comment: When you say `split`, do you mean there can only be one separation from the original array? So if `a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]`, it can't be split like `b = [ 2, 3, 4 ], c = [ 1, 5, 6 ]`?

Comment: If it *works* -> Codereview it

Comment: Also what does the input array look like? Arbitrary numbers?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Initially, there is an array,  A , containing  N integers. N <= 2^14

Comment: @Fabjan Please, read the question started from `After each successful partition ..`

Comment: I don't know if it's slow or not, but for { 4, 5, 9 } it returns 0 while it should return 1.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Probably, but I'm still not sure what are the "partition" rules. For instance, given { 1, 4, 3 }, what is the answer - [A] 0 (the number positions are fixed) [B] 1 : { 1, 3 }, {4} or [C] 4 (all permutations): {1, 3}, {4} + { 3, 1}, {4} + {4}, {1, 3} + {4}, {3, 1}

Comment: @IvanStoev Please, look ar https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-splitting

Comment: It's not clearly defined there either. But looks like by partition they mean split, i.e. for my previous example the answer is [A]

Comment: @IvanStoev Partitions are contiguous. Thankfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quite efficient way:

```
static int CalcScore(int[] a)
{
    return CalcScore(a, 0, a.Length - 1, a.Sum(n => (long)n));
}

static int CalcScore(int[] a, int startPos, int endPos, long totalSum)
{
    long leftSum = 0;
    long rightSum = totalSum;
    for (int splitPos = startPos; splitPos < endPos; splitPos++)
    {
        leftSum += a[splitPos];
        rightSum -= a[splitPos];
        if (leftSum > rightSum) break;
        if (leftSum == rightSum)
        {
            int leftScore = CalcScore(a, startPos, splitPos, leftSum);
            int rightScore = CalcScore(a, splitPos + 1, endPos, rightSum);
            return 1 + Math.Max(leftScore, rightScore);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The main algorithm is in the second recursive method. First, it uses precalculated total sum. Second, it uses an inclusive array index range defined by `startPos` and `endPos`, which allows us to avoid memory allocations. Then it simple iterates from start to end - 1  adding the current value to the left sum and subtracting it from the right sum until the left sum becomes larger than the right sum, in which case it early exits (this is based on the constraint that values are not negative), or if both sums are equal, it counts the split and adds the maximum splits of the left and right parts recursively.

**UPDATE:** Taking into account the fact that the array range can be split on tow parts with equal sum only if the total sum is divisible by 2 (hence the target left and right sum should be the half of the total sum), the recursive part can further be optimized like this:

```
static int CalcScore(int[] a, int startPos, int endPos, long totalSum)
{
    long halfSum = totalSum / 2;
    if (halfSum + halfSum != totalSum) return 0;
    long leftSum = 0;
    for (int splitPos = startPos; splitPos < endPos; splitPos++)
    {
        leftSum += a[splitPos];
        if (leftSum > halfSum) break;
        if (leftSum == halfSum)
        {
            int leftScore = CalcScore(a, startPos, splitPos, halfSum);
            int rightScore = CalcScore(a, splitPos + 1, endPos, halfSum);
            return 1 + Math.Max(leftScore, rightScore);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I run this code through hackerrank, but it just pass once test

Comment: Hmm, what it could be. Integer overflow may be. Does it say something?

Comment: Now it's passing all the tests :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public Tuple<int[], int[]> SplitIntArray(int[] array, int index) {
    return new Tuple<int[], int[]>(
        array.Take(index).ToArray(),
        array.Skip(index).ToArray()
    );
}
public string AggregateSumString(int[] array) {
    return array.Select(i => i.ToString()).Aggregate((sumString, next) => 
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(sumString) ? next : String.Format("{0} + {1}", sumString, next))
}
```

Then,

```
int[] array;
var results = new List<Tuple<int[], int[]>>();

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    var tuple = SplitIntArray(array, i);

    if (tuple.Item1.Sum() == tuple.Item2.Sum()) {
        results.Add(tuple);
    }            
}

// results contains all pairs of arrays that sum to the same value.
foreach (var tuple in results) {
    Console.WriteLine(
        String.Format("{0} == {1}", AggregateSumString(tuple.Item1), AggregateSumString(tuple.Item2)));
}
```

Comment: If we assume the numbers are all random within a range and spread randomly, the most solutions will lie more to the middle of the input array. Instead of iterating from 0 I suggest iterating from array.Length/2 in both directions.

Comment: Upvote for a good suggestion, but I've designed my answer to cover *every* combination of array sums; if they were randomly, then `[ 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4 ]` would not mean that starting from `array.Length / 2` is any more effective. Agreed that on average, however, that would be more effective if every combination didn't have to be tested.

Comment: What is the `firstArray` and `secondArray`?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko Sorry, typo

Comment: Also `sumString` must be `int`, but not a `string`, according to Aggregate signature

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko forgot to convert the inputted `int[]` to `IEnumerable<string>`, which I did through `.Select()`. Apologies for sloppy code checking, was just a quick dirty output method to format the results nicely!

Comment: I have an error 'System.Tuple<int[],int[]>' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko Updated again.